# Project Euler: 45 (or More Python Generators)

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

This is [problem 45](https://projecteuler.net/problem=45) from Project Euler:

> Triangle, pentagonal, and hexagonal numbers are generated by the
>   following formulae:
>
> Triangle        Tn = n x (n+1) / 2        1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ...
>
> Pentagonal      Pn = n x (3n−1) / 2       1, 5, 12, 22, 35, ...
>   Hexagonal       Hn = n x (2n−1)           1, 6, 15, 28, 45, ...
>
> It can be verified that T285 = P165 = H143 = 40755.
>
> Find the next triangle number that is also pentagonal and hexagonal.

Here is my code:

```
def triangle_generator():
    n = 1
    while True:
        t = n * (n + 1) // 2
        yield t
        n += 1


def pentagonal_generator():
    n = 1
    while True:
        p = n * ((3 * n) - 1) // 2
        yield p
        n += 1


def hexagonal_generator():
    n = 1
    while True:
        h = n * ((2 * n) - 1)
        yield h
        n += 1


def tph():
    tg = triangle_generator()
    pg = pentagonal_generator()
    hg = hexagonal_generator()

    tg_temp_list = []
    pg_temp_list = []
    while True:
        h = next(hg)
        t = 0
        p = 0
        while t < h:
            t = next(tg)
            tg_temp_list.append(t)
        while p < h:
            p = next(pg)
            pg_temp_list.append(p)
        if h in tg_temp_list and h in pg_temp_list:
            print("Found! {}".format(h))
        else:
            tg_temp_list = tg_temp_list[-2:]
            pg_temp_list = pg_temp_list[-2:]
```

So, a hexagonal number is yielded, then two temporary lists are populated—one from `triangle_generator()`, and one from `pentagonal_generator()`. Then, it is checked whether the yielded hexagonal number is in both those lists. If not, the temporary lists are emptied, except the last element, another hexagonal number is yielded, and the whole procedure repeats indefinitely.

My question: (Assuming purely mathematical approaches aside) Does Python provide more convenient (Pythonic) ways to implement the `tph()` function?

Comment: change your temp_list to a set would slightly increase efficiency but not by more. regarding your question, why do you mean by "more convenient ways"? this seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps more elegant, not sure much more efficient. But the idea is that if you can merge iterators where the lowest # is returned on each pop, i.e. priority queue, then your code can be cleaner.

```
import heapq

def tph():
    tg = triangle_generator()
    pg = pentagonal_generator()
    hg = hexagonal_generator()
    count = 0
    last_n = 0
    for n in heapq.merge(tg, pg, hg):
        if n == last_n:
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 1

        if count == 3:
            print(n)

        last_n = n
```

Comment: Thanks. It sure looks cleaner. Read the `Heap queue algorithm` from Python docs. Still trying to figure out how/why your code works.

Comment: @blackened Are you familiar with a heap/priority queue? I don't know the internals of `heapq.merge`, but I assume it just generates and keeps track of the minimum and only inserts when necessary, i.e. lazy.

The algo is assuming: 1. the generators don't repeat themselves. 2. If you get the same number 3 times in a row, then each generator must've output 1 of those.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by computing and evaluating every next triangular, pentagonal and hexagonal numbers as you have done already, but Project Euler problems are primarily designed to be a good mix of clever mathematics and programming. From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_number), we have that **every hexagonal number is a triangular number**.

Hence, we solely need to iterate over the hexagonal numbers, and stop as soon as we find one that is also a pentagonal number! By some simple mathematics, we find that a number is pentagonal if and only if `(sqrt(24 * candidate_value + 1) + 1) / 6` is integer.

Then, the problem reduces to the following code:

```
import math


i = 144

while True:
    hexagonal = i * (2 * i - 1)

    if ((math.sqrt(24 * hexagonal + 1) + 1) / 6).is_integer():
        print("Found it! The next occurence is {}".format(hexagonal))
        break
    i += 1
```

Comment: @Wouda Thanks. I forgot to mention that point in my post (now edited), that my sole intention is to improve my Python.

Comment: @blackend, while I do understand what you are trying to say, I'd definitely argue that minimalism is in and of itself very Pythonic!

Comment: @blackend if you want it more 'functional', you can express it as a generator for the hex numbers and a predicate for the pentagonal ones. filter one with the other. I think the mistake you might be making is reading 'generates' in the problem description and turning everything into a python generator. That ends up being a lousy match for the problem.